# Syntax error when importing mysql table with html code in it

Tags: mysql, import, mysqlimport

Im trying to import a mysql table with data that has html code in it and it generates syntax error. Can someone tell me how to properly import mysql with html code

Sytanx error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<ul>\r\n<li>Unpack the equipment and materials</li>\r\n<li>Secure the mounting '
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you get

Comment: @Daniel edited the post

Comment: How did you create that file? Some tools should not be used for DB export.

Comment: Show us the SQL statement.

Comment: How are you trying to import the data? mysql command line, mysql workbench, phpmyadmin, php, ??? It's hard to solve the problem without knowing more details.

Comment: To answer your question, we'll need a bit more. If you post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I expect you'll have an answer in under 30 minutes.

Comment: Please tell us how are you importing the data? As, I'm able to import mysql table containing html text using phpmyadmin

Comment: It tells us `''<` you have to single quotes (the first is the start of the single quotes being used by my sql the second is a rouge quote in your SQL) in there so it's complaining your HTML has single quotes in it and not `&#39;` as it should have for single quotes. i'm also unsure why you have a single quote in front of a <ul> that makes no sense... you need to go through and escape all your HTML to be SQL safe

Comment: Whatever program generated the SQL, it did it wrong. Export it again using a proper tool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the very little you have shown us the error i can see that it's complaining about a rouge single quote `'`

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<ul>\r\n<li>Unpack the equipment and materials</li>\r\n<li>Secure the mounting '
```

If you notice at the start of the quoted text from MySQL it has `''` and at the end it only has `'` MySQL errors show the problem code at the start location in single quotes so we remove one single quote wrapping the errored syntax we end up with

`'<ul>\r\n<li>Unpack the equipment and materials</li>\r\n<li>Secure the mounting`

So it's complaining about a single quote before a `<ul>`. you need to make sure you HTML is MySQL safe before entering it into the Database so replace single quotes as `\'` or if it's supposed to be rendered you should use `&#39;`

if your using php you can use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) to escape any single quotes `'` with `\'` before entry.

Another option is to stop using directly constructed queries and use prepare & bind_param in your connector as it will then prevent this from happening.

Unfortunately, however, If you're using mysqlimport cli and this is a prebuilt .sql file your gonna have to go through it by hand and fix it I highly recommend a syntax enabled editor to do this [MySQL workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) it the best for MySQL syntax